# Not updating database and not throwing error in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have an issue while updating the user. When I try to update the user after clicking the save button then it redirect me to the same page and not throwing me any error but also its not updating anything in the database. Below is my code. I have no idea what's going on here. Help me :)

**Controller**

```
public function update(ReportRequest $request, $id)
{
    $report = Report::findOrFail($id);
    $input = $request->all();

    if ($file = $request->file('photo_id')) {
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('images', $name);
        $photo = Photo::create(['file' => $name]);
        $input['photo_id'] = $photo->id;
    }

    $report->update($input);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::resource('admin/reports', 'ReportController', ['names'=>[

    'index'=>'admin.reports.index',
    'create'=>'admin.reports.create',
    'edit'=>'admin.reports.edit',

]]);
```

**Models**

```
class Report extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'student_id',
        'student_name',
        'class_id',
        'subject',
        'teacher_name',
        'report_categories_id',
        'total_marks',
        'obtained_marks',
        'percentage',
        'position',
        'photo_id',
    ];

    public function photo() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Photo');
    }

    public function studentsClass() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\StudentsClass', 'class_id');
    }

    public function student() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Student');
    }


}
```

Comment: Please show us your route and view code.

Comment: @Hasnain did you set fields in `fillable` array?

Comment: Function update of Modal only update when have a least a attribute is changed. Do you sure have a field value is changed

Comment: Here is my updated answer. You can check that

Comment: @HasnainKahn Have you set enctype in your form?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your `$fillable` properties in your `Photo` and `Report` models, otherwise the `create()` and `update()` methods won't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Check the $fillable fields in the Model as above. If the error persists check your laravel log on storage/logs/laravel.log.

Comment: My $fillable fields are okay. I checked that again and again.

Answer (score 0):

In controller:

```
public function update(ReportRequest $request, $id){
    $report = Report::findOrFail($id);
    $input = $request->all();

    try{
        if ($request->photo_id != '') {

            $path = 'images/';
            $file = $request->photo_id;
            $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move($path, $name);

            $photo = Photo::create(['file' => $name]);

            $report->update(['photo_id' => $photo->id]);

        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        return redirect()->back()->with('error_message', $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```